# Discord Bot written in Python minigame while loop not working

Tags: python, bots

This piece of code i wrote for a Discord Bot is not working and i would like to find out why and how to make it work and maybe different methods.

```
def russian_roulette(author, message):
    game_active = True
    client.send_message(message.channel, "Russian Roulette game started.6 chambers. 1 loaded.\nType $spin to spin the chamber.\nType $pull to pull the trigger.")
    while game_active == True:
        if message.content.startswith('$spin'):
            chamber = randint(1,6)
            client.send_message(message.channel, "%s spins the chambers." % author)
        if message.content.startswith('$pull'):
            if chamber == 1:
                client.send_message(message.channel, "%s pulled the trigger and was not lucky. R.I.P." % author)
                game_active = False
            else:
                client.send_message(message.channel, "%s pulled the trigger and nothing happened." % author)
```

Comment: What's not working about it? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example and explain what exactly the issue is

Comment: @James Well when I get to this function it prints the 3rd line of code as i expected it but once it reaches the while loop and i type in the command nothing happends. Also sorry for not putting an MCVE

Comment: I don't know how the discord API works or what your implementation is, but it looks like you're infinitely looping and never updating the message variable or author variable, so the program will just spin its wheels endlessly. You'll likely need to attach some sort of listener function to author or message rather than infinitely loop

Comment: @James Thank you. I am very new to programming and appreciate the help. Would you mind referring me to somewhere where I can learn about listener functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using [this API wrapper for discord](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py).

In that case, what you'll need to do is create a function with the decorator client.event so that it responds to messages properly. Like so:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$spin'):
            chamber = randint(1,6)
            client.send_message(message.channel, "%s spins the chambers." % author)
    if message.content.startswith('$pull'):
        if chamber == 1:
            client.send_message(message.channel, "%s pulled the trigger and was not lucky. R.I.P." % message.author)
            game_active = False
        else:
            client.send_message(message.channel, "%s pulled the trigger and nothing happened." % message.author)
```

This function will be called every time your bot receives a new message, rather than in your code in which the function will only be called once.

Note that I've never used this API before and am simply reading the documentation and examples - this could be incorrect.

Comment: Something clicked in my mind reading your implementation of the code and I got it to work. Thank you.